# Laravel paginator an all pages

Tags: laravel-4, pagination, paginator

I have an paginator that I use for my forum.

The problem is, when I include this, it displays on every page, including the pages that doesn't need to have the pagination jet.

How Can I fix this?

Now I have this to display my pagination:

`{{ $comments->links() }}`

Comment: What if you just don't include {{$comments->links}} in the pages that don't need pagination?

Comment: They all need the pagination once... If the comments are more then 10 Here is my code: http://laravel.io/bin/1y0Ym | http://laravel.io/bin/BLmy5

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you changed the default view for a paginator to your own - because Laravel hides pagination when it isn't needed.

This is how Laravel handles this:

```
<?php
$presenter = new Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapPresenter($paginator);
?>

<?php if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1): ?>
<ul class="pagination">
        <?php echo $presenter->render(); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you can find it in:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/views/slider-3.php
```